# What is the best way to create a conditional question in case activities?

Tags: drupal, civicase, condition

I currently have cases with different activities in CiviCRM for different programs. I then used custom fields to add additional questions to appear in each activity in the forms. Is it possible to set conditional questions to appear based on a prior question?

P.S. I'm currently using CiviCRM on Drupal. However, I like to keep using the case activities form instead of a Webform for the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CiviCRM does not have a built-in way to create conditional fields in its forms. You mentioned Drupal Webforms and yes they could solve that problem for you if you were open to using a webform instead.

Otherwise the only solution is to learn to write jQuery code and customize your form by showing/hiding fields with javascript.

Comment: Thanks, Coleman. Another way I tried to solve this was to create activity types and custom fields for these situations.